# how to show username, name after login on laravel

Tags: laravel, authentication, user-information-list

I created login with code =

[image: login code]

and now I want to show username, name after login, how to write the code for it?
thank all

Answer (score 0):

Hello if you using the default auth model you can get the currently authenticated user via `Auth::user()`.

For name: `Auth::user()->name;`

For email: `Auth::user()->email`;

Answer (score 0):

The `attempt` method is normally used to handle authentication attempts from your application's "login" form. If authentication is successful, you should regenerate the user's session to prevent session fixation:

```
public function process(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->validate([
        'username' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        $request->session()->regenerate();

        return redirect('/');
    }

    return back()->with(['error' => 'Login Gagal']);    
}
```

[Retrieving the authenticated user](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#retrieving-the-authenticated-user) :

```
// Retrieve the currently authenticated user...
$user = Auth::user();

dd($user->username);
```